# WaitForElement not working for confirmation dialog

Tags: android, automation, xamarin.android, automated-tests, xamarin.uitest

After execution of this code:

```
_app.WaitForElement(_sendMoneyScreen.btnConfirm, "Timed out", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
_app.Tap(_sendMoneyScreen.btnConfirm);
```

This piece of code is not working:

```
 // Waiting for Dialog
_app.WaitForElement(_mainMenuScreen.dlgNotification, "Timed out", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout));
```

After tapping confirm button a loader is displayed and then a notification dialog is expected which both are not displayed during execution.

Comment: I'd recommend that you review how to use `REPL` when designing your tests.  When inside `Repl`, try the `tree` command - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/repl/